# Windows Application Memory Consume

Tags: memory-management, windows

I have several Windows Applications working together on a 24-hour working factory's production band. I have a memory consuming problem in one of the devices. It's an only-touchscreen, I don't know the proper way to say it, it only consist of screen, with Intel Atom as processor.

I don't have Lists with thousands of elements that would consume huge portions of memory. I use database connections, form creation etc. operations with **using blocks** and I also use IDisposable.

I traced the memory, garbage collector works but it has a delay around 5 minutes.

What could cause that kind of problem, is there any tools that speeds up **Garbage Collection**(stand-alone application or .NET framework)? Does visuals of Forms consume memory too much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a memory leak somewhere, [here is a good article for debugging memory leaks.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19490/Memory-Leak-Detection-in-NET)